# changing variable name in box plot using fct_recode

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to change the variable name using fct_recode(), but getting an error, could anyone please suggest how to fix it?

```
    bpdata <- read.table("Box.plot.chemical.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
 
        bpdata[,"SampleType"] <- as.factor(bpdata[,"SampleType"])
    bpdata <- cbind(row.names(bpdata),bpdata)
    names(bpdata)[1] <- "sample"
   
    
    
             
  data <- melt(bpdata, id = 1:5,variable.name="name")
  data$SampleType <- factor (data$SampleType, levels = v_factor_levels)
    ########################################################
    
    #using forcats::fct_recode()
    data<-data %>%
      mutate(name = fct_recode(name,"Rice_P" = "Rice_P(mg/kg)","Rice_Mn" = "Rice_Mn(mg/kg)")) #"new value" = "old value"
    
    ########################################################
   

Error;

    Warning message:
    Problem with `mutate()` input `name`.
    ℹ Unknown levels in `f`: Rice_P(mg/kg), Rice_Mn(mg/kg)
    ℹ Input `name` is `fct_recode(name, Rice_P = "Rice_P(mg/kg)", Rice_Mn = "Rice_Mn(mg/kg)")`.
```

Comment: You're missing a couple of `"`, try `mutate(variable = fct_recode(variable,"Rice_P" = "Rice_P(mg/kg)","Rice_Mn" = "Rice_Mn(mg/kg)"))`.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly. I was putting the old name first but actually, it was just the opposite.

```
data<-data %>%
  mutate(name = fct_recode(name, `Rice_P(mg/kg)` = "Rice_P" , `Rice_Mn(mg/kg)` = "Rice_Mn" )) # `new value` = "old value
```

Many thanks,